# Best Learning Resource for OAuth

Tags: android, http, authentication, rest, oauth

I have to use OAuth for my Android client and I have found that the learning resources are pretty rare or inadequate for this technology.

Does anybody know a good book/tutorial/online resource to learn OAuth?
Thank you.

Comment: It took me longer than I expected to implement. Are you just implementing it in your client or do you need to know about the server part too?

Comment: Yeah this thing is pretty cumbersome and I know I am not the only one. Right now I am assuming the server part may be done by somebody else.

Answer (score 3):

hi Kunjan avoidin the OAuthocalypse???

heres is a excellent example to implement OAuth for Twitter in Android

http://github.com/brione/Brion-Learns-OAuth by Brion Emde

heres the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25o0b2aEw0E)

if you have any question I will help you

Answer (score 3):

I see this has more or less been answered, however with recent development in the OAuth spec old tutorials and sample code might or might not work (at least I had difficulties to make it work based on old blog posts here and there).  I summarized how I did it on Android here:

http://nilvec.com/implementing-client-side-oauth-on-android/

Answer (score 2):

This is the page that finally made it click for me:

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/11/07/google-oauth-overview/

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to figure out OAuth myself, and I've written a [blog post](http://codebrook.wordpress.com/2010/07/14/twitter-oauth-in-c-for-win32-part-2/) with example code which accesses Twitter via OAuth.

The code is C++/Win32, however it might help give you an idea of what's involved.  There are also links to the relevant resources I used throughout the post, which may be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [the official wiki](http://wiki.oauth.net/)?

Also, most providers have their own documentation for the OAuth process, for example [Twitter](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq)

Comment: the official wiki is NOT a good resource.  it is vague, confusing and plagued with broken links.